# How to check against a value in mysql before INSERT

Tags: mysql

Hio Guys, I have the following SQL query;

```
INSERT INTO ps_ext_mod (id_order,product_reference,id_customer,email)
SELECT d.id_order, d.product_reference, o.id_customer, c.email
FROM ps_orders o
INNER JOIN ps_order_detail d ON d.id_order = o.id_order
INNER JOIN ps_customer c ON c.id_customer = o.id_customer
```

What I need to happen is to check the table ps_ext_mod if id_order already exists with the value to be inserted. If it does, then dont insert it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just join back to the table and look for where the join fails, i.e.:

```
INSERT INTO ps_ext_mod (id_order,product_reference,id_customer,email)
SELECT d.id_order, d.product_reference, o.id_customer, c.email
FROM ps_orders o
INNER JOIN ps_order_detail d ON d.id_order = o.id_order
INNER JOIN ps_customer c ON c.id_customer = o.id_customer
LEFT JOIN ps_ext_mod em ON em.id_order = d.id_order
WHERE em.id_order IS NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do it in pure SQL then there is :

```
If (SELECT count(*) FROM ps_ext_mod WHERE id_order = ?) == 0) THEN (Other SQL)
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/if-statement.html

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO ps_ext_mod (id_order,product_reference,id_customer,email)
SELECT d.id_order, d.product_reference, o.id_customer, c.email
FROM ps_orders o
INNER JOIN ps_order_detail d ON d.id_order = o.id_order
INNER JOIN ps_customer c ON c.id_customer = o.id_customer
LEFT JOIN ps_ext_mod m on m.id_order = d.id_order 
where m.id_order is null;
```